# Windows 10 - Are there any shortcuts to access the tasks or items within a taskbar Jump-List,

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, taskbar, shortcuts, jumplist

I've pinned MS Outlook as my first taskbar item and its very convenient to access some quick tasks via keyboard shortcut `Windows Key + Alt + 1`

Thing is I use the keyboard shortcut to open the jump list, but I've to further click on the task I want to perform (like New Email, New Meeting etc)

Question is, is there any shortcut or keyboard only way to access the tasks within the jump list? I'm looking for a direct shortcut like  `Windows Key + Alt + 1 + ??` = `New Meeting`